# Flask ошибка: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcd in position 0: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

я пытаюсь запустить приложение на Flask, но выдаёт ошибку:

```
* Serving Flask app 'hello' (lazy loading)
* Environment: production
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
Use a production WSGI server instead.
* Debug mode: off
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Python/flask_blog/hello.py", line 9, in <module>
app.run()
File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 922, in run
run_simple(t.cast(str, host), port, self, **options)
File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 1008, in run_simple
inner()
File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 948, in inner
srv = make_server(
File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 780, in make_server
return ThreadedWSGIServer(
File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 686, in __init__
super().__init__(server_address, handler)  # type: ignore
File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\socketserver.py", line 452, in __init__
self.server_bind()
File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\http\server.py", line 140, in server_bind
self.server_name = socket.getfqdn(host)
File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\socket.py", line 756, in getfqdn
hostname, aliases, ipaddrs = gethostbyaddr(name)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcd in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

Код:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return 'Hello, World!'
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5000,debug=True)
```

Как это исправить?

Comment: Установите Python 3.9, там вроде починили

Comment: Да и 3.8 работает. Кириллица в названии компьютера есть? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64176529/error-after-using-flask-run-unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byt

Comment: Ага, только его до 3.8.11 обновить надо

Comment: 3.8.8 все работает. Так что думаю проще будет убрать кириллицу из названия компа, если там кириллица.